# Install MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mysql, ubuntu-12.04

Only version 5.5 is available through apt-get, but I want to install 5.1.

1. Is there a way to install it through apt-get? Perhaps by adding a certain repository.
2. How can I install it manually without apt-get? There were instructions in the compressed file provided by MySQL that worked reasonably well, but I had issues connecting through it and I think there were some things missing that is provided through a .deb package.

I wasn't able to find any good resources on installing it manually apart from the INSTALL-BINARY that came with it.

Comment: "I want to install 5.1" What for? 5.5 does pretty much everything 5.1 does.

Comment: And if you don't want the latest greatest, why 12.04 as opposed to 10.04?

Comment: What about [this technique](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56084/installing-old-mysql-server-4-1-on-ubuntu-11-04) OR [Installing MySQL from a Standard Source Distribution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing-source-distribution.html)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not able to migrate from 5.1 to 5.5 yet.

Comment: @emgee Why do I have to stay on an older OS just because of the version of database I want? 5.1 isn't that old.

Comment: @MatthewReid Thanks for the links, those are the instructions in INSTALL-BINARY that I had some issues with. I guess I'll have to try them again.

Comment: @mangoDrunk you're absolutely right, you can get MySQL 5.1 to work in the newer version of Ubuntu. But for simplicity's sake, I personally would use 10.04 anyway, as MySQL 5.1 is in the repositories, is a snap to maintain and 10.04 Server is an LTS version, supported by Canonical until 2015. Just my $.02

Comment: @emgee Good point, I guess I should start checking what software is supported in the newer version and see if I should update or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was [MySQL Sandbox](https://launchpad.net/mysql-sandbox). With MySQL Sandbox, I was able to install MySQL 5.1 self-contained in one folder which is better in my opinion than having MySQL using many different folders which is harder to uninstall which may have been the reason for issues with installing 5.1 manually after having installed 5.5. With MySQL Sandbox, I'm able to have multiple instances of MySQL installed without them conflicting with one another.